# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO found

Tags: python, flask, text-extraction, bytesio

I am trying for a week how to give input files to Textract from flask POST option.

```
@app.route('/input', methods=['POST'])
def input():
    request_file = request.files.get('file')
    r = textract.process(io.BytesIO(request_file.read()))
    return r
```

The above code throws me error

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO
>   found

And I tried a small test with `send_file` to check if it actually takes the input and to check if BytesIO works well in my case:

```
@app.route('/input', methods=['POST'])
def input():
    request_file = request.files.get('file')
    return send_file(io.BytesIO(request_file.read()),attachment_filename=
request_file.filename)
```

the above code works fine for pdf files and send responses(to download pdf file). And when i tried .docx,.txt files it show some strange outputs on the screen :   PK

My questions, how do i send this `io.bytes(request_file.read())` as a file to Textract now ? I tried to find answer everywhere but i couldn't.

Am i supposed to decode or encode now?

Comment: `r = textract.process(io.BytesIO(request_file.read()).read())`?

Comment: Not working . Throws error : TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str

Answer (score 1):

`textract.process()` expects a string, but you send `io.BytesIO(request_file.read())` instead. I'm not really sure why you're using `io.BytesIO`. Can you try:

```
textract.process(request_file.read())
```

Comment: It gives error : TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str . This read() is reading the contents and not sending the file to textract

Comment: I got it working by saving the input file to the disk by using `os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)` . But request_file.read() is not working for me (I thought of working without saving it on the disk :/ )